# Grouping by multiple fields in Nodejs using Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am currently grouping my data by account but also need to group it by salesperson too. However, I cannot figure out how to successfully implement the functionality so that it is grouping by multiple fields at the same time. Could someone offer up some guidance as to how I can do that?

Here is my function that groups my data as of right now:

```
filteredData[rep.id] = _.chain(filteredData[rep.id]).groupBy('account').map(function(v, i) {
          return {
              customer: i,
              salesperson: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
                  return val['salesperson'];
              },0),
              sales_ytd: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
                  return res + Number(val['sales - ytd']);
              },0),
              mgn$_ytd: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
                  return res + Number(val['margin - ytd']);
              },0),
              sales_last: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
                  return res + Number(val['sales - pytd']);
              },0),
              mgn$_last: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
                  return res + Number(val['margin - pytd']);
              },0)
    }
}).value();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the field values when you need to group by multiple fields.

Example (not tested):

```
filteredData[rep.id] = _(filteredData[rep.id])
  .groupBy(function(o) {
    return o.account + '-'  + o.salesperson;
  })
  .map(function(v, i) {
    var customer = _.head(_.words(i));

    return {
        customer: customer,
        salesperson: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
            return val['salesperson'];
        },0),
        sales_ytd: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
            return res + Number(val['sales - ytd']);
        },0),
        mgn$_ytd: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
            return res + Number(val['margin - ytd']);
        },0),
        sales_last: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
            return res + Number(val['sales - pytd']);
        },0),
    mgn$_last: _.reduce(v, function(res, val) {
        return res + Number(val['margin - pytd']);
    },0)
};
```

}).value();

Comment: this works great and solved the problem...thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is a little unclear to understand your code without the input data and the expected result, but, I believe that you are grouping the data and formatting the result on one sweep. maybe you could consider separating the concerns of the function writing:

```
const formatData = (object, index) => {
  return =  {
    customer: index,
    salesperson: _.reduce(object, function(res, val) {
        return val['salesperson'];
    },0),
    sales_ytd: _.reduce(object, function(res, val) {
        return res + Number(val['sales - ytd']);
    },0),
    mgn$_ytd: _.reduce(object, function(res, val) {
        return res + Number(val['margin - ytd']);
    },0),
    sales_last: _.reduce(object, function(res, val) {
        return res + Number(val['sales - pytd']);
    },0),
    mgn$_last: _.reduce(object, function(res, val) {
        return res + Number(val['margin - pytd']);
    },0)
  }
}
```

Then you could iterate over a list of grouping clases and return an object containing several groups:

```
const groupFormatedDataBy = ( ...groupingClasses ) => {
  let output = {}
  grupingClasses.forEach(groupingClass => {

    output[groupingClass] = _.chain(filteredData[rep.id])
       .groupBy(groupingClass)
       .map( formatData )
       .value();

  })

  return output
}
```

PS: I could not test the code without sample data jejeje, hope it helps you